# How to enable FQL in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, fql

Please let me know how to enable "FQL" in SharePoint Online site.

I am getting error if I use `enablefql=true` in a query text.

Comment: To use FQL, you need to create a result source and configure it to use query transformation in the first place. Have you done this?

Comment: How to configure the result source with FQL transformation. Please let me know

Comment: It's instructed in a lengthy documentation which Microsoft provides online at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/plan-to-transform-queries-and-order-results. See also https://support.office.com/en-us/article/understanding-query-transforms-b31631a5-0c1f-436e-8061-fd807bb96ae1 to understand what query transforms are and are used for.

Answer (score 0):

To EnableFQL, you need to modify the query transformation in the content source.

Follow below steps of creating a new result source and changing the query transformation to use FQL:

1. Remove the KQL filter, `-ContentClass:urn:content-class:SPSPeople`, from the Query Transformation. The resulting Query Transformation string will be: `{?{searchTerms}}`.
2. Replace the Query Transformation string with an FQL equivalent, such as `{?andnot({searchTerms},filter(contentclass:"urn:content-class:SPSPeople*"))}`.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint